# go unable to find net.Resolver

Tags: go

I have installed go 1.7 in Debian to make [doh](https://github.com/m13253/dns-over-https)

It has a Makefile, which triggers the download and install of dependencies into my `GOPATH`.

The `net` package is there:

```
$ ls $GOPATH/src/github.com/golang/net/
AUTHORS         context          dict  http   idna      ipv6     lif      PATENTS       README.md  webdav
bpf             CONTRIBUTING.md  dns   http2  internal  lex      nettest  proxy         route      websocket
codereview.cfg  CONTRIBUTORS     html  icmp   ipv4      LICENSE  netutil  publicsuffix  trace      xsrftoken
```

Yet during the build, it says it cannot find net.Resolver

```
$ make
go get -d -v ./doh-client ./doh-server
cd doh-client && go build
# _/home/share/apps/dns-over-https/doh-client
./client.go:47: undefined: net.Resolver
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'doh-client/doh-client' failed
make: *** [doh-client/doh-client] Error 2
```

This is my first go with go, so I am not sure how it goes about pulling in imports, and whether the Resolver part is present.

Comment: How did "net" end up in `src/github.com/golang`?  The reason I ask is I don't see the code importing github.com/golang/net, but rather net which are two different things

Comment: @sberry I had assumed it was pulled in from the dependencies - but I was trying different fixes to understand how it worked, and it is possible I did a manual `go get` and put it there.

Comment: @sberry Aaah, that would explain it.  If I installed golang/net myself, could that be why it cannot find the Resolver thing because it is the wrong net?

Comment: Does `go run <name_of_file.go>` work when `name_of_file.go` are these contents: https://play.golang.org/p/gRY_gJK1yUu ?

Comment: @sberry Yes, it does, no errors

Comment: Ah, it appears `net.Resolver` (or something else) is not present in 1.7.  From the README: `Install Go, at least version 1.9.`

Comment: For the record, net.Resolver was [introduced in 1.8](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#minor_library_changes).

Comment: @sberry Ooops, thanks.